# Знаки ??? вместо слова

Tags: php

Я сделал чат с помощью MySQL и выбираю тип сообщения 1251 general_ci но сообщения выбивает ???? подскажите что делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проверьте кодировку полей в базе, кодировку файлов отвечающих за чат, и кодировку в теге <head>. либо попробуйте после mysql_connect добавить строку mysql_query('SET NAMES cp1251');

Comment: Спасибо, заработало =)

Answer (score 1):

Товарищ oOKomarOo, вынужден Вас расстроить, но **1251 general_ci** в БД - это **способ сортировки**, а не кодировки.